# WPF: The Output is Correct But the Window doesn't show up

Tags: c#, wpf, do-while, timespan

I am developing a WPF application. I need a method to run every 5 seconds and output the information it captures. I used the difference of DateTime to decide if 5 second has passed. When I started running it, I could see the correct information is outputted every 5 seconds. However, the app's window didn't show up, neither could I find it's icon in status bar. Here is my code public MainWindow():

```
InitializeComponent();            
    DateTime now;
        DateTime _lastTime5SecondsHadPassed = DateTime.Now; ;
        TimeSpan elapsed;
        do
        {
            now = DateTime.Now;
            elapsed = now - _lastTime5SecondsHadPassed;
            if (elapsed.Seconds >= 10)
            {
                title = GetActiveWindowTitle();
                Trace.WriteLine(title);
                _lastTime5SecondsHadPassed = DateTime.Now;
            }

        } while (true);
```

Later I found whichever window I moved the this code into, other windows would appear normally but everytime when it switch to the window with this code, the window would not show up. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an endless loop which blocks the MainWindow constructor forever. Quite obviously the window won't show up. Throw all that code away, and use timer instead, preferrably a DispatcherTimer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clemens is absolutely correct. The current code you are producing an endless loop which does not allow for the rest of the program to continue on.

The following code is shamelessly stolen from [WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer/).

Xaml for Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Misc.DispatcherTimerSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DispatcherTimerSample" Height="150" Width="250">
    <Grid>
        <Label Name="lblTime" FontSize="48" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfTutorialSamples.Misc
{
        public partial class DispatcherTimerSample : Window
        {
                public DispatcherTimerSample()
                {
                        InitializeComponent();
                        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
                        timer.Start();
                }

                void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                        lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                }
        }
}
```

You will note that the constructor for the Window creates a timer for 1 second. Every second, the label on the window will be updated to the value for `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()` (e.g. 10:30:15).

Comment: Please mark answers as correct so others know the question has been solved. It is the checkmark below the voting (to the left of the answer).